# Angular: No duplicates in the code (transfer to service)

Tags: angular

I have a code that I use a lot when booting the app:(ngOnInit)

```
  this.route.queryParamMap.subscribe(
  params => {
    const id = params.get('id');
    if (id) {
      this.contactsService.GetContactByUserId(id)
        .subscribe(
          response => {
            this.contact = response;
          }
        )
    }
  }
)
```

I want to move this thing to service.
And I will call the method from the service and not every component to add this part

What I was trying to do:

Service:

```
displayNameById(){
    this.route.queryParamMap.subscribe(
      params => {
        const id = params.get('id');
        if (id) {
          this.GetContactByUserId(id)
            .subscribe(
              response => {
                this.contact = response;
              }
            )
        }
      }
    )
  }
```

In the component I called this method:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.contactsService.displayNameById();
  }
```

Of course it does not work, does not display what I am asking for in html:

```
{{contact.displayName}}
```

Comment: Are you using `onPush detection strategy?`

Comment: @tony I do not even know what it is

Comment: Search for `changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` in your component, check if it exists

Answer (score 0):

In you service

```
constructor(private activeRoute: ActivatedRoute){}
displayNameById(){
  if(this.activeRoute.snapshot.params[key]){
   const id = this.activeRoute.snapshot.params[key];
   this.GetContactByUserId(id);
   return  id;
  }
}
```

and in your component you can call it in ngOnint:

```
ngOnInit(){
 let id = this.contactsService.displayNameById();
}
```

Comment: are you talking about this.GetContactByUserId(id) method?

Comment: you can call it in if block, updated my answer now you can check

Comment: key is which you passing in params ,in your case it is "id" so replace key with "id"

Comment: I could not figure out how to pass the ID if it is set only after I tried to add an id parameter but it did not work

Comment: are you passing id in queryparam of the route?